# Error: EACCES: permission denied, rename '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli'

Tags: angular, react-native, npm, expo, eas

I came accross this error that seems to be a permission issue, took me a while so i just wanted to share a solution I found for this.

If other solutions ?, please share them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The current solution I found for this issue is to change the permissions to the current user.

```
sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

then try running

```
npm install -g <dependency>
```

Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

First i do

```
ls -la
```

Identify which folders not below to my user and run

```
sudo chown -R $USER <FOLDER>
```

Answer (score 0):

for me it was;
sudo chown -R "User/mac/.npm"
and then;
npm cache clean --force

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but inside a project I was working on.

Curiously, the first time I ran `npm i`, it worked, but when I ran it again, I got the same error.

Here's a slightly more detailed method for resolving the error

### Make sure npm shall run

1. Open the terminal
2. Run `sudo chown -R $(whoami) ~/.npm`

### Inside your project *(I'm opening it with vs-code)*

1. Run the `npm i`
2. You'll see the error `EACCESS` - `path: '/Users/[thePath]/[my-project]/node_modules/...`
3. Copy the first part of the path, till `node_modules` -> `/Users/[thePath]/[my-project]`
4. Open a terminal
5. Run `sudo chown -R $USER /Users/[thePath]/[my-project]`
6. Wait a bit, it will run recursively *due to `-R`* and give write access to every file
7. Inside your project, run the `npm i` again, this should work ;).